# Property or method is not defined in vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm getting this error

> Property or method "test" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

I'm not sure why I'm getting it. As far as I know I'm calling `test` correctly.

Here is my code

My controller

```
    $test = [
        'test' => 'test'
    ]

    return view('index', ['test' => $test]);
```

My blade file

```
    @section('content')
        <div id="index">
            <index :test="test"></index>
        </div>
    @endsection
```

My index.js

```
    Vue.component('index', require('./components/Index').default);
    
    if (document.getElementById('index') != null) {
        const app = new Vue({
            el: '#index'
        });
    }
```

and here is my Index.vue

```
    <template>
        <div>
            My vue template
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            props: ['test'],
            data() {
                return {

                }
            },
            methods: {

            },
            mounted() {

            },
        }
    </script>
```

Maybe I forgot to add something, but I'm not sure

Comment: you need to pass `props` and like that you cannot

Comment: @KamleshPaul - but am I not doing that already in my blade file and my Index.vue?

Comment: `<index test="test"></index>` try this

Comment: I'm getting `Trying to get property 'test' of non-object` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your blade file to:

```
@section('content')
        <div id="index">
            <index test="{{ $test['test'] }}"></index>
        </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: When I did that I got this error `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` and when I changed `{{ }}` to be `{!!  !!}` I got `array to string converstion` error

Comment: Thats why you should send the array element `$test->test`, not the full array

Comment: When I did that I got this error `Trying to get property 'test' of non-object`

Comment: Ah sorry, updated my answer, `$test['test']` is the way to acces it